# Merge (implode) values of a field in second row with values of same field in first row in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to merge (implode) values of a field(mark_internal) in second row with values of field(mark_internal) in first row?

```
print_r($marks);
```

**output:**

```
    Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
   [id] => 10 
   [year] => 2016-2017 
   [mark_internal] => 2005SD00000001:10,3,1,1,2|2005SD00000002:6.8,2.4,1,1,1) 

[1] => Array ( 
  [id] => 11 
  [year] => 2016-2017 
  [mark_internal] => 2000SD00000001:9,2,1,1,1|2000SD00000002:7.8,2,1,1,2)
```

**desired output:**

```
stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 10 
[year] => 2016-2017 
[mark_internal] =>2005SD00000001:10,3,1,1,2|2005SD00000002:6.8,2.4,1,1,1|
                  2000SD00000001:9,2,1,1,1|2000SD00000002:7.8,2,1,1,2)
```

Comment: No built-in way to do that. You'll need to loop on the values manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using foreach achieve this

```
<?php
$a = array(
0 => array(
   'id' => 10,
   'year' => '2016-2017',
   'mark_internal' => '2005SD00000001:10,3,1,1,2|2005SD00000002:6.8,2.4,1,1,1'),

1 => array(
  'id' => 11,
  'year' => '2016-2017',
  'mark_internal' => '2000SD00000001:9,2,1,1,1|2000SD00000002:7.8,2,1,1,2')
);

$s = '';
foreach($a as $key => $data)
{

    $s .= $data['mark_internal']."|";
}
echo $s;
?>
```

> OUTPUT:
>   2005SD00000001:10,3,1,1,2|2005SD00000002:6.8,2.4,1,1,1|2000SD00000001:9,2,1,1,1|2000SD00000002:7.8,2,1,1,2|

[PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dtgs-mfkh)